# Understanding Eclipse Memory Analyzer Report

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I've been having a tough time trying to figure out the source of my OOM errors.

The memory analyzer report says that a certain instance of BitmapDrawable occupies ~16 MB so I thought I'd start there. However, I'm not sure how the memory can be accumulated in an instance of "byte[]". Any advice about how to interpret this report or what might be going wrong would be much appreciated.

[image: Eclipse MAT heap dump analysis problem suspect 1]